# In dictionary output is not getting as expected in PYTHON

Tags: python, dictionary

here response in an dictionary which is having form values stored in an dictionary. My output is generatd with seperate dictionary which i doesnot need seperately. I want all the elements in one dictionary only

```
resp = {}
b = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    resp_i = form.getvalue('opt_%d' %i, '0')
    resp[i] = int(resp_i)
    arg =  {i : resp[i]}
    b.append(arg)
    #print len(b)
for each in b:
    print each
```

Actual Output: {1: 1} {2: 1} {3: 3} {4: 1} {5: 3} {6: 0} {7: 0} {8: 0} {9: 0}

Expected output:  {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 1, 5: 3, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}

Comment: I think you need to print resp rather than b[]..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
b = []
for ...
   arg = {i: resp[i]}  # creates a new dict
   b.append(arg)  # adds the dict to the list
```

What you're probably looking for is something like:

```
b = {}
for ...
    b.update(arg)
```

Of course, this still isn't the cleanest way to do it.  After all, why create all the temporary dictionaries?

```
b = {}
for ...
   b[i] = resp[i]
```

would work, or you could probably even pull it all into a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: @user3003685 -- Given your code, have you tried to put `print resp` at the end of the loop?  I think that might actually be good enough.

Comment: Thanks.. I have update one more the same, but unable to solve that

Answer (score 0):

```
def form_getvalue(i):
    return ('0', '1', '1', '3', '1', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0')[i]

resp = {}
for i in range(1, 10):
    resp[i] = int(form_getvalue(i))

print 'resp=%s' % (resp,)
```

The output of the above is:

```
resp={1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 1, 5: 3, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}
```