# Dictionary output is not as expected in PYTHON

Tags: python, dictionary

Here prsnson.result contains the data which are comming from an query. I want the expected output, but its not coming. I am using python 2.5

```
for row in prsnobj.result:
    ansdb = {row[0] : row[1]}
    print ansdb
```

Actual: {1L: 3L} {2L: 4L} {3L: 2L} {4L: 2L} {5L: 2L}

Expected: {1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2}

Comment: Related: [In dictionary output is not getting as expected in PYTHON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486939/in-dictionary-output-is-not-getting-as-expected-in-python)

Comment: there is no solution of this question onet that qurestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers fetched from a database is commonly returned as `Long` when utilizing the different database interfaces.

If you want the output you're after

```
ansdb = {}
for row in prsnobj.result:
    ansdb[int(row[0])] = int(row[1])
```

Perhaps the [MySQL documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) for Python could help clear things up

Comment: OP wants a single dict, not multiple dicts.

Comment: I wouldn't say always - it depends on the interface you are using

Comment: yes i dont want multiple dictionary...i want is all in one dictionary

Comment: Man, people here are starting to get lazy. One would think that the actual problem was getting ints from the longs and appending unique keys to a dict would be the easy task.

Answer (score 0):

All the L means is that it's in long integer (64-bit) form, so your returned value is indeed still correct. When you create a new dictionary with entries already in there (as you are), it's going to automatically convert all of the entries to long form; instead you should use a tuple or simply print each one in the loop itself:

```
for row in prsnobj.result:
    print row[0] + " : " + row[1]
```

or

```
for row in prsnobj.result:
    ansdb = (row[0], row[1])
    print ansdb
```

Depending on how your prsnobj object was defined, you may end up getting long integers still. If so, you need to look back at the code that defines prsnobj and check that it was created properly. Use printouts to make sure that the object is always in the state that you want it to be in!

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in prsnobj.result:
    ansdb = {int(row[0]) : int(row[1])}
print ansdb
```

you result type is long， you should tranfer to int

Comment: i dnt want multiple dictionary